# Confusion regarding path specification and output comparison

Tags: bash, shell-script

Basically I created a set of tests, that i want to run through, run the test and then compare them with the one's i've got from my before-hand made output files.

So far I've got this

```sh
for file in ./tests/*.test; do
# Now I'm unsure how can I get the output of a file stored in a variable.
# I did this, but I'm unsure whether it's correct
./myexec "$file"
returned=$?
# So if my understanding is correct, this should run my desired test and store STDOUT
# Next I want to compare it to what I have inside my output file
compared="$(diff returned ./tests/"$file".output)"
if [ -z $compared ]; then
   echo "Test was successful"
   passed=$((passed + 1))
else
   echo "Test was unsuccessful, got $ret but expected ./tests/"$file".output")
   failed=$((failed + 1))
# I presume that one above is an incorrect way to print out the expected result
# But I couldn't really think of anything better.
```

Either way, this is probably fundamentally wrong on multiple levels, but I'm new to shell so this would be pretty helpful for me to improve my understanding

Comment: The line ... compared="$(diff returned ./tests/"$file".output)" is probably wrong. You probably do not want to execute "diff return ..." Especially since you just set "returned" to $? (which is either going to be 0 or some error code).  You probably want "return" to be set to the output "./myexec $file" not the return code. So try return=$(./myexec $file).

Answer (score 0):

`returned=$?` doesn't store STDOUT to `returned`. It stores the exit code of the last command executed, namely of `./myexec "$file"`.

Assuming `./tests/"$file".output` holds the expected result, what you mean is for example this:

```
# first assign the value properly using the command substitution
return=$(./myexec $file)

# Then compare using process substitution, as diff demands a file to compare.
## And the process  substitution passes diff the file descriptor of its STDOUT.
compared="$(diff <(echo "$returned") ./tests/"$file".output)"
```